# multiple ggplots overall title

Tags: r, ggplot2

Hi I am using a solution that is on Cookbook for R to plot multiple ggplots in one go...i.e. the code from this bottom of the page on this link http://wiki.stdout.org/rcookbook/Graphs/Multiple%20graphs%20on%20one%20page%20(ggplot2)/

I would like to add an overall title to this plot but am not sure how to do it. i.e. I would like to be able to have an amended function that has the additional argument for title like the below

```
multiplot(..., plotlist=NULL, file, cols=1, layout=NULL, title="")
```

any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 9, accepted):

use the `gridExtra` library and the function `grid.arrange` to do this. Example:

```
 p1 <-qplot(factor(cyl), data=mtcars, geom="bar")
 library(gridExtra)
 grid.arrange(p1, p1, p1, p1, main = "Overall Title")
```

See `?grid.arrange` for more options.

Comment: For those viewing this later: With R 3.4.0 and gridExtra version 2.2.1, argument `top` worked for me, instead of `main`

Comment: I also had to use `top` flag.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
multiplot <- function(..., plotlist=NULL, file, cols=1, layout=NULL, title = "") {
    library(grid)
    
    # Make a list from the ... arguments and plotlist
    plots <- c(list(...), plotlist)
    
    numPlots = length(plots)
    
    # If layout is NULL, then use 'cols' to determine layout
    if (is.null(layout)) {
        # Make the panel
        # ncol: Number of columns of plots
        # nrow: Number of rows needed, calculated from # of cols
        layout <- matrix(seq(1, cols * ceiling(numPlots/cols)),
                         ncol = cols, nrow = ceiling(numPlots/cols))
    }
    
    if (numPlots==1) {
        print(plots[[1]])
        
    } else if (title == "") {
        # Set up the page
        grid.newpage()
        pushViewport(viewport(layout = grid.layout(nrow(layout), ncol(layout))))
        
        # Make each plot, in the correct location
        for (i in 1:numPlots) {
            # Get the i,j matrix positions of the regions that contain this subplot
            matchidx <- as.data.frame(which(layout == i, arr.ind = TRUE))
            
            print(plots[[i]], vp = viewport(layout.pos.row = matchidx$row,
                                            layout.pos.col = matchidx$col))
        }
    } else {
        # Set up the page
        grid.newpage()
        #We add one row for the title
        pushViewport(
            viewport(
                layout = grid.layout(
                    nrow(layout) + 1,
                    ncol(layout),
                    heights = c(1, rep_len(10, ncol(layout)))
                )
            )
        )
        grid.text(label = title, vp = viewport(layout.pos.row = 1, layout.pos.col = 1:ncol(layout)))
        
        # Make each plot, in the correct location
        for (i in 1:numPlots) {
            # Get the i,j matrix positions of the regions that contain this subplot
            matchidx <- as.data.frame(which(layout == i, arr.ind = TRUE))
            
            print(plots[[i]], vp = viewport(layout.pos.row = matchidx$row + 1,
                                            layout.pos.col = matchidx$col))
        }
    }
}
```